# How do I reset the CMOS in a Lenovo T500?

Tags: cmos

I've got my Lenovo T500 in a state where the display output doesn't work.

I want to reset the CMOS to factory defaults.

I have removed the keyboard, disconnected the internal battery and counted to 10 before reconnecting it however this didn't work.

What else can I do?

Comment: You need to remove the AC power and battery pack, if you didn't.  You may also simply need to wait longer. That said, how do you know it didn't work if the display isn't working?